# Send Data Via Http In C#

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, api

I am creating Android Application for a school where teachers should be login to the android application and perform some activity on daily basis.

We have a complete existing web based solution for the same and now want to implement same in Android.

The application is developed in Asp.net and C#

To authenticate a user on android login, I have created a login API which takes username and password in the query string and in return the API return Json Data From That User.

example : `www.yourdomain.com/authenticateuser.aspx?username=xxxx&pas=YYYYY`

But I doubt whether its safe to send the data via query string. 
Can anybody suggest a better possible way where it is not mandatory to send the data in Query String.

Comment: No, it's never safe to send password in that way. A man-in-the middle approach (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) can get all access info. Is it possible the use of https? An interesting link: stackoverflow.com/questions/6443401/performing-login-to-https-website-via-android-app

Comment: If you want to do that, use HTTPS and send it in the `content`. When the password is a password in the DB, you should send the hash of the password, not plain text!!

Comment: How To Create API, which will accept the parameters like the example in your link??  @Seraphim

Comment: its not only password i have to send, there are other sensitive data which i need to send, Can We use GET Or SET for the same???

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Soap` based web-service. I created a demo to consume `Soap` Web-service without `KSoap` Library.

Ref Link: [SoapWithoutKSoap](https://github.com/Abhan/SoapWithoutKSoap)

You can use `KSoap` Library to create complex `Soap Data` Request.

I hope this can help you.

C# Web-Service: [Demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Demo1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_web_services.htm)

***UPDATE***

Web Service Link will be something like this : `http://123.456.789.012/Abhan/Abhan.asmx?op=JustTest` (This is not working as I modified the IP Address)

In Browser, method name and passing parameter(s) information will be like something as attached image.

[image: ASP.Net Service]

Thanks.

Comment: i want to create the C# API first, as i dont know how to do that!!  please help

Comment: @RobertRay Answer updated. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @Abhan Interesting! But why don't you like ksoap?

Comment: @Seraphim Project web service does not have any complex data to send in request and moreover I wanted to try something new. As I did not test performance regarding without `KSoap` but working smoothly in project.

Comment: i created webservice but not able to use that , if you want i can provide the web service address

Comment: @RobertRay Is it local or live? If live, I can test that. Thanks

Comment: @RobertRay Where is the link? Please See Updated Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using C# web services to autenticate users, send report data and get app updates.

You can get some exmaples in the web (C#):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

and ksoap2 for Android:

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

But I also bought a SSL certificate to use https...

Comment: i created a Webservice but i am not able to use it in android

Comment: what kind of problem? Can you open the url (with a browser) and see the wsdl like http://yoursite.com/TheWebServiceName.asmx?WSDL ?

Comment: wait i will give you live Link @seraphim

Comment: i have created two API's
First :
http://www.moneyheaps.com/checkuser.aspx?id=1
It Returns The Json Result As You See, you can use id=2 as well for a test
i am able to connect This With Android and Parse the Json As well  But the Secure Data gets displayed in Querystring and thats not safe 

Second:
http://www.moneyheaps.com/User.asmx
i tested the web service locally and it displays the Correct Json but i am not able to Fetch Json From The Android , Please help @Seraphim